# "Undefined index" only for "file" field in HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

This was working but stopped afterwards.
Other fields have no issue submitting.
When I press submit the other fields are added to the database but this one is not.
To prevent confusion the value that matters is photo_url not photo_dir.
Further clarification: photo_dir is the value of a drop down menu with a compass direction. All I want is to store the file name in the DB under column photo_url.

This is the form field

```
<label for="photo_url">Upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="photo_url">
```

This is the SQL

```
$sql="INSERT INTO photo(photo_project_id,photo_section,photo_subsection,photo_date,photo_post,photo_desc,photo_url,photo_dir)VALUES('$_POST[photo_project_id]','$_POST[photo_section]','$_POST[photo_subsection]','$_POST[photo_date]',now(),'$_POST[photo_desc]','$_POST[photo_url]','$_POST[photo_dir]')";
```

The file is also being uploaded to the server which is working without issue. Though I would like to be able to rename them to datetime() but that is a topic for a different day.

Comment: As an aside, you should never pass POST variables straight into an SQL query. You code as it is currently is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I will be preparing the statements in the final version. However if I did not all that would happen is that you would get your own data because of the application. If you can link me to a step by step guide however that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: That is asking what it means. This is asking g what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to file element with $_FILE like this

```
$_FILES['photo_dir']
```

in the first step print_r this because it has another child

Comment: Same error. Doubt that was it since it was working before with $_post.

Comment: Do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form?
print_r($_FILES["photo_dir"]) it should give you data of uploaded file

Comment: Yes I do. The weird thing is the file upload script uses the same $_FILES["photo_dir"] and it has no issues working. I am using the code in the w3schools link to handle the upload (with some modifications).

Comment: you can not save $_FILES["photo_dir"] to db because it is an array, you can save one index of that for example $_FILES["photo_dir"]["tmp_name"]

Comment: @MajidAbbasi, he put his input file name as `photo_url` so definitely he wouldn't get anything inside  `$_FILES['photo_dir']`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion photo_url is the value we are looking at not photo_dir

Answer (score 0):

First of all your should have this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for using input type file, Should look like this :

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

After form submit, check :

```
if(isset($_FILES['photo_url'])){
 $file_name = $_FILES['photo_url']['name'];
}
```

Rewrite query then :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO photo(photo_project_id,photo_section,photo_subsection,photo_date,photo_post,photo_desc,photo_url,photo_dir)VALUES('$_POST[photo_project_id]','$_POST[photo_section]','$_POST[photo_subsection]','$_POST[photo_date]',now(),'$_POST[photo_desc]','$_POST[photo_url]','$file_name')";
```

Comment: photo_dir is completely unrelated and has to do with in which direction the photo was taken! I should clarify that photo_url is the value I am looking at.

Comment: For the rewrite should it be: $sql="INSERT INTO photo(photo_project_id,photo_section,photo_subsection,photo_date,photo_post,photo_desc,photo_url,photo_dir)VALUES('$_POST[photo_project_id]','$_POST[photo_section]','$_POST[photo_subsection]','$_POST[photo_date]',now(),'$_POST[photo_desc]','$file_name','$_POST[photo_dir]')";

Comment: I don't know what you are getting inside `$_POST[photo_dir]`. What i have created a variable that will return you the file name. You can append your image directory with file name to save full path inside database.

Comment: photo_dir is the value of a drop down menu with a compass direction. All I want is to store the file name in the DB under column photo_url